# Create a taskoverview with JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to show whithin my Java application wheather a person is free or blocked on a particular date.
I made an example of my intention in Power Point:

[example chart](http://s22.postimg.org/iiix5z45t/chart.jpg)

My first intuition was to use JFreeChart. Therefore I created some tasks and put them together in
one taskseries for each Person.

With this data i created a Gantt chart. 
But in a Gantt chart every task is placed into a new Line and the axis a far away from my intention.

[image of unuseful gantt chart](http://s12.postimg.org/hpyfi6c99/gantt.jpg)

is it possible to create a chart like my example chart with JFreeChart?
What would be the best way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

See [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartGanttDemo2withmultiplebarspertask.htm).

Comment: hm, it looks like he is using task.setPercentComplete(0..1) to draw a small bar into a big bar.
But my intention is to put equal sized bars in one row next to eachother (see my example chart)
or I'm not getting it?
thanks in advance!

Comment: The percent complete bar is just an added feature. You can leave it out and then you still have the bars in one row next to eachother.

Comment: explaining:
you create a "main" task from the very start date to the very end date and name it "Person". then you create sub tasks which are the real tasks.